# shuffle of column 2d list in dart

Tags: dart

I am trying that after creating a multidimensional list in Dart it is Shuffle by Columns. The idea is that the values associated with the indexes of list 2, when list 1 is reordered, maintain their correspondence. For example, for index 27 of both lists, index 0 is 6 | 6, which corresponds to index 27 of list 1 and it is 12.

Comment: main() {
  int n = -1;
  int s = -1;
  List<dynamic> fichas = List.generate(2, (i) => List(28), growable: false);
  for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
    s = s + 1;
    for (int b = s; b < 7; b++) {
      n = n + 1;
      String t = ((a.toString()) + '|' + (b.toString()));
      int t1 = (a + b);
      fichas[0][n] = (t);
      fichas[1][n] = (t1);
    }
  }

  //fichas[0].shuffle();
  //fichas[1].shuffle();

  print(fichas[0]);
  print('');
  print(fichas[1]);
}

Comment: Maybe consider another data structure if columns in a row should be locked together? E.g. consider make a `List<Row>` where `Row` is a class you have defined to contain your columns.

Comment: Thanks Jule.   So I resolved to sort the second list so that the relationship is maintained  ///Ordenar la lista[1] a partir de la lista [0]
  n = -1;
  for (var cara in fichas[0]) {
    var a = int.parse((cara.toString().substring(0, 1)));
    var b = int.parse((cara.toString().substring(2)));
    int t1 = (a + b);
    n = n + 1;
    fichas[1][n] = (t1);